# Postgres: two dictionaries with same name

Tags: postgresql, dictionary

I've created a text search dictionary using the following query.

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY english_stem 
(TEMPLATE = snowball, Language = english, StopWords = english);
```

But I realized that there was already a dictionary with same name 'english_stem' which is owned by superuser and I ended up having two dictionaries with same name 'english_stem'; one owned by super and one owned by me.

So I tried to drop the one that I created using this query:

```
DROP TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY english_stem;
```

But I am getting "[42501] ERROR: must be owner of text search dictionary english_stem" message. I guess the drop query is trying to drop the english_stem dictionary owned by superuser, not owned by me. How can I drop the english_stem dictionary owned by me?

If postgres allows multiple dictionaries with the same name, I guess there must be a way to differentiate them when executing alter/drop command on them.

By the way, probably due to the one created by me, tsquery is slow; even slower than like query.

Note: I am looking for a way to resolve this without contacting the super user.

Comment: you created it in different schema - just specify full path

Answer (score 1):

I believe you created dictionary in your schema or in public. Check out:

```
SELECT * from  pg_catalog.pg_ts_dict 
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = pg_ts_dict.dictnamespace;
```

If so, just add schema name, like:

```
DROP TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY public.english_stem;
```