# postgres: Index on full text search does not work

Tags: postgresql, dictionary, indexing, full-text-search

I did in the following order.
Added tsvector column

```
ALTER TABLE MYTABLE ADD COLUMN SEARCHABLE_TEXT TSVECTOR;
```

And populated with an existing column

```
UPDATE MYTABLE SET searchable_text = to_tsvector('english', MYCOLUMN);
```

And this query took around 200ms

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE
WHERE searchable_text @@ to_tsquery('text');
```

Now created an index

```
CREATE INDEX MYTABLE_FTS_IDX ON MYTABLE USING GIN (SEARCHABLE_TEXT);
```

And the same select query took around 10 - 15ms. This worked in my local Postgres box.

So I did the same thing on my production box, but the same select query is still taking 200 - 300ms even after creating MYTABLE_FTS_IDX index. Why would the index do not work on certain instance although I applied same thing?

One different thing I can think of is, I've created a english_stem dictionary and deleted on the production box as I stated on other question [Postgres: two dictionaries with same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38782190/postgres-two-dictionaries-with-same-name)

The number of records in local is 17k, and the number for prod is 40k. And the number of select result is around 400 - 500 record.

Here is the result of explain analyze:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on product  (cost=15.50..1255.12 rows=451 width=1447) (actual time=0.140..0.690 rows=452 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (searchable_text @@ to_tsquery('jean'::text))
  Heap Blocks: exact=363
  Buffers: shared hit=366
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on product_search_idx  (cost=0.00..15.39 rows=451 width=0) (actual time=0.100..0.100 rows=452 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (searchable_text @@ to_tsquery('jean'::text))
        Buffers: shared hit=3
Planning time: 0.223 ms
Execution time: 0.781 ms
```

Another weird thing is that, if I search using 'jean', it shows result although it's slow.  But if I **search using 'jeans', it shows 0 record**! I feel like something went wrong.

My Postgres version is PostgreSQL 9.4.5 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16), 64-bit

Comment: also post number of rows in production. result of explain and also did you run vacuum analyze?

Comment: Thanks @e4c5  question is updated.

Comment: but did you vacuum ? and what about the explain analyze?

Comment: Thanks @e4c5 I am a Java developer, so not much knowledge on this.  I will see how to do vacuum and how to get explain analyze.

Comment: By the way, if I search to_tsquery('pant'), the result shows all records with **pants**, but if I search to_tsquery('pants'), then result shows zero record! I would expect the same result. Should I use different dictionary?

Comment: @e4c5 here is the explain: 
Bitmap Heap Scan on product  (cost=15.37..1221.22 rows=435 width=1447) (actual time=0.123..0.642 rows=452 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (searchable_text @@ to_tsquery('jean'::text))
  Heap Blocks: exact=363
  Buffers: shared hit=366
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on product_search_idx  (cost=0.00..15.27 rows=435 width=0) (actual time=0.084..0.084 rows=452 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (searchable_text @@ to_tsquery('jean'::text))
        Buffers: shared hit=3
Planning time: 0.195 ms
Execution time: 0.738 ms.

Comment: I don't see **Heap Blocks: exact=363** in my local Postgres. work_mem for local is 1MB and work_mem of prod is 4MB. What would be a problem and how can I fix that?

Comment: you will agree that the explain is very unreadable as a comment. Please update the question.

Comment: Also I did vacuum, but didn't help.

Comment: Thanks @e4c5 the question is updated.

Comment: Also updated the number of records.

Comment: Note how the planning and execution time at the end of the explain add up to about 1 ms. All the other time the query seems to take is probably the time it takes to transfer the result set over the network or overhead in the program you used to measure the query time.